# Is it posible to check how much memory browser is using and clear memory currently using by javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am stuck with big problem i working on big project that is hanging browser automaticaly javacript executes
"how to detect how much memory javascript is using and clear the memory in regular interval.Is it posible?"

Comment: i doubt it. which browser are you talking about?

Comment: i m talking about every browser especially chrome and firefox...

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any way to play with memory. Javascript runs in a sandbox environment, so you have no access to memory management in any way. The garbage collector takes care of this, and you *can* somehow make it do what you want, but it's random. Don't count on it.

Rather, for your problem, you can use Chrome Inspector's Profiler.

[image: Profiler]

What does it do? Well... it profiles the webpage you're in. You can see how long each function takes, and especially: *where is your bottleneck*.

Answer (score 2):

Try in Chrome, specifically.

Chrome's V8 has a brilliant generational garbage collector, where three types of polling happens: There are three threads constantly polling the three generation types, and I think they run at 10, 50 and 200 millisecond intervals (I may have got the figures wrong, but they are principally similar, with the time intervals increasing for older generations).

This is aggressive, and ensures that memory usage remains low.

In spite of this, if your code is hogging memory in Chrome, then you can be sure that the issue is with the code. It could be that:

(a) Your code is really unoptimized, or 
(b) It is really working on very large data that is probably not best suited for the client (e.g. an excessively heavy page that has tons of widgets, dom nodes etc.)

Care to post some snippets?